# Does flask_Login have a require_anonymous decoractor functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I have a flask app working with with flask_login.  When a logged in user goes to certain urls, for example the registration URL, I would like them to be redirected somewhere, and a flash message sent that they can't visit that page while logged in.  However I don't see that kind of decorator being available.  I'd rather not add code to each function to do these checks.  I suppose I could write my own decorator, but it'd be nice if it were part of flask_login

Comment: An idea in my mind is that, you can use @app.before_request decorator in flask and perform a check inside that decorator to get the URL on which user is making request, if you want to restrict the user to hit that URL, you can redirect user to another "Access Denied: landing page. I have implemented the same logic in my small project.

Comment: This function will run before each and every endpoint you have in your application. Once the code within this function has completed, the code within the actual endpoint that initiated the before_request() method will run.

Comment: I'll look into that option, it would still be nice if a simple decorator were built into the module.  I started last night to try follow what was done for other decorators in a forked version of the repo, if I can get that to work, then I'll probably offer it up to the project.